# C# LINQ OrderBy on nullable -> Always set null values at the end of the list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, nullable

Is there an easy way to sort a list on nullable values, by ascending, and put the null values at the end of the list ? Like an option or something

If not, which method would be the best between  :

1. Write my own sort lambda

   ```
   list.Sort((v1,v2) => 
   {
      if (v1.HasValue && v2.HasValue) return v1.CommpareTo(v2);
      else if (!v1.HasValue) return -1;
      else if (!v2.HasValue) return 1;
      else return 0;
   })
   ```
2. Sort only the non-null values, and add null values after

   ```
   list.Where(v => v.HasValue).OrderBy().AddRange(list.Where(v => !v.HasValue)
   ```

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(x => x.HasValue).ThenBy(x => x)`.

Comment: `list.Where(v => v.HasValue).OrderBy().AddRange`  I am surprised that even compiles, or works.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot the ThenBy ! Thanks
Yes the ToList() before AddRange is missing